# Remove XFCE Start-Up/Loading/Boot Screen While Keeping XFCE

Tags: boot, unity, xubuntu, xfce

I've recently gotten Xfce on my Unity machine. I want to keep Unity and Xfce, but how do I remove the boot/loading screen that says "Xubuntu" when I want it to say "Ubuntu" like it did before I installed Xfce. Please help!

EDIT: I did `dpkg-query -W | grep plymouth` and it returned

```
libplymouth4:amd64  0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1
plymouth    0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1
plymouth-label  0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo  0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text  0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1
plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo 16.04.2
plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text 16.04.2
```

Comment: Maybe uninstall Unity and reinstall it. I have a similar problem in Xubuntu: i  installed lubuntu-desktop in it,  and now a **horrific** login wallpaper is freaking me out each time i want to login. I tried to change it manually with another jpg file, but that messes both the xfce and lxde login. My guess is that the last one installed is assuming leader role and acts very boss.

Comment: @ipselute Thanks for the help, I'll try doing it. But is there a risk of messing up my machine?

Comment: This is easy; Run `dpkg-query -W | grep plymouth` in Terminal and [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/791750/edit) to paste the output. I can tell which package to uninstall.

Comment: @clearkimura Will try!

Comment: Simpy remove or purge the relevant packages that provide "Xubuntu" boot splash. The remaining "Ubuntu" boot splash will be restored. More details in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boot splash was changed to "Xubuntu" instead of "Ubuntu" because the following packages were installed together with Xubuntu meta package:

```
plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo 16.04.2
plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text 16.04.2
```

These packages are dependencies of [`xubuntu-artwork`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xubuntu-artwork) package, which is in turn, one of the dependencies of [`xubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xubuntu-desktop) meta package. You can also check this by running `apt-cache rdepends <PACKAGE>` to check reverse dependencies for particular package.

### Removing "Xubuntu" boot splash

To permanently remove the boot splash, run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get purge plymouth-theme-xubuntu*
```

This command will select both packages above by using an asterisk `*` as wildcard, which is convenient to remove multiple packages with similar prefix naming.

Finally, reboot to see changes.

### Alternative commands

You can also do the same by specifying the package names.

```
sudo apt-get purge plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text
```

With recent versions of APT, the command can be as short as below.

```
sudo apt purge plymouth-theme-xubuntu*
```

Regardless of any command above, no further configuration is needed. APT will run relevant commands and reconfigure the boot splash automatically for you.